# Making a mark all as read button

Tags: button, html-helper

So as the title says i want to make an extension that when clicked marks all the messages (emails in this case) as read instead of going through every single one to get it marked

i would assume its simply finding the html code for the button and making it so it clicks on every emails that is not read?

example:[HTML Code of button regarding emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7kZr.png)

So i should make something that reads if its read or not right? or would it just be easier to run it to click all buttons with the same name?